# how to append data that you got from case statement

Tags: mysql, join, case

i am using below code :

```
select t2.lPortfolioItemId, t2.seAssignment,t3.dAcquisition as dAcquisition, 
(' Hardware Repair Level: ' || 
(CASE 
WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > SysDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > SysDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported'
END 
)as 
 t3.Status as Status from (((((amPortfolio t2 left outer join amEmplDept t7 on t2.lUserId=t7.lEmplDeptID)
inner join amAsset t3 on t2.lAstId=t3.lAstId) inner join amModel t6 on t3.lModelId=t6.lModelID) left outer join amAstCntrDesc t4 on t3.lAstId=t4.lAstId) left outer join amContract t5 on t4.lCntrId=t5.lCntrId) 
where t2.lAstId<>0;
```

i want the value that i am getting from case statement  to be appended to Hardware repair level field.
Should i assign a new variable to fetch the value or there is some other way to do that?

Comment: `CONCAT('yourString', CASE WHEN .. THEN .. [ELSE .. ]END)`. But this kind of 'formatting' should be done in the application, not in the database in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select t2.lPortfolioItemId, t2.seAssignment,t3.dAcquisition as dAcquisition, 
    CONCAT(' Hardware Repair Level: ',
        (CASE 
            WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > SysDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > SysDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported'
        END 
    )) as t3.Status as Status
from 
    (((((amPortfolio t2 left outer join amEmplDept t7 on t2.lUserId=t7.lEmplDeptID)
    inner join amAsset t3 on t2.lAstId=t3.lAstId) 
    inner join amModel t6 on t3.lModelId=t6.lModelID) 
    left outer join amAstCntrDesc t4 on t3.lAstId=t4.lAstId) 
    left outer join amContract t5 on t4.lCntrId=t5.lCntrId) 
where t2.lAstId<>0;
```

### Update

Use this query according to your comments

```
select t3.dAcquisition as dAcquisition, 
    CONCAT(     ' Contact: ', 
                t3.MaintContact, 
                ' Hardware Repair Level: ', 
                (CASE WHEN (t3.Status <> 'Disposed' OR t3.TR_PSSpares <> 1) THEN 'Vendor Not Supported' WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > GetDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > GetDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported' END ) 
        ) as SupportRemarks 
from ((amPortfolio t2 left outer join amEmplDept t7 on t2.lUserId=t7.lEmplDeptID) inner join amAsset t3 on t2.lAstId=t3.lAstId)
```

`CONCAT` is a function which takes multiple parameters and concatenates all of them. In your case 'Contact' is first paramter, `t3.MaintContact` is second paramter, ' Hardware Repair Level: ' is third parameter and 'Vendor Supported' from `CASE` is forth paramter

You should also check the proper syntax for `CASE` statement. For every `WHEN` part you should provide a `THEN` part. And its a good practice to provide an `ELSE` part to be on safe side for unhandled cases e.g.

```
CASE WHEN a=b THEN 'both are equal' WHEN a<b THEN 'a is less than b' ELSE 'b is less than a END
```

Comment: i pasted just a small part of the code but concat is not wrking so putting detailed code:
select t2.lPortfolioItemId(' Contact: '|| t3.MaintContact ||CONCAT(' Hardware Repair Level: ',
(CASE
WHEN ((t3.Status <> 'Disposed') OR (t3.TR_PSSpares <> 1))
THEN 
CASE 
WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > SysDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > SysDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported'
END
as SupportRemarks,from (((((amPortfolio t2 left outer join amEmplDept t7 on t2.lUserId=t7.lEmplDeptID)
inner join amAsset t3 on t2.lAstId=t3.lAstId)
According to the error that i m getting looks like its related to syntax but not able to figur out y....

Comment: @DeepanshAnand, this is not correct SQL, maybe the comment styling has messed up with it. Please update your question with complete code

Comment: i am unable to update code in questn 
select t3.dAcquisition as dAcquisition,

(' Contact: ' || t3.MaintContact || CONCAT(' Hardware Repair Level: ',
(CASE 
WHEN (t3.Status <> 'Disposed' OR t3.TR_PSSpares <> 1)
THEN
CASE
WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > GetDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > GetDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported'
WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd IS NULL) OR  (t5.dEnd IS NULL) OR (t3.dWarrEnd < GetDate()) OR (t5.dEnd < GetDate())) THEN 'Best Effort'
END
) ))
) )
as SupportRemarks 
from 
(((((amPortfolio t2 left outer join amEmplDept t7 on t2.lUserId=t7.lEmplDeptID) 
inner join amAsset t3 on t2.lAstId=t3.lAstId)

Comment: @DeepanshAnand, why are you using ||? do you want to `CONCAT` 'Contact: <t3.MaintContact> Hardware Repair Level: Vendor Supported' all as one column or 'Contact: MaintContact' and one column and 'Repair Level: Vendor Supported' as another column

Comment: i want all the data in a single field so contact,hardware repair level as 1 column

Comment: also other fields are working fine but when i am updating and trying to concatenate then i am getting error :(
format that i am using is:

t3.MaintContact || CONCAT(' Hardware Repair Level: ',
(CASE 
WHEN (t3.Status <> 'Disposed' OR t3.TR_PSSpares <> 1)
THEN
CASE
WHEN ((t3.dWarrEnd > GetDate()) OR (t5.dEnd > GetDate())) THEN 'Vendor Supported'
END

Here only something is wrong but i am not able to figure it out :(